Least Absolute Deviations – Geometric Intuition
I've recently been exposed to the geometric intuition regarding Least Squares (OLS) regression:
The vector of the outcome variable $Y$, is not not in the linear span of $X_1, X_2, ..., X_{p-1}$:

The orthogonal vector $Y-X\hat{B}$ is that which minimizes the $l^2$-norm of the error vector and solves the least squares problem.
My question is: for the least absolute deviations (LAD) problem, where we instead want to minimize the $l^1$-norm, is there any intuition for what projection solves the LAD problem? It is not necessarily the orthogonal vector above (and LAD solutions are not necessarily unique).
This is really more of a linear algebra question than anything: What will the projection look like if we want to minimize the $l^1$-norm?

There is no projection associated with the $L^1$ norm.  There is a geometric explanation, given in 1757 by R. Boscovitch, as explained (and illustrated) by Stephen Stigler in his History of Statistics.

@whuber How can there be no projection associated with $L^1$ norm? Don't we need a $\hat{Y}$ vector in the span of $X$ to obtain coefficients (regardless of the objective function)? Thank you for pointing me to that text.

That's might be some kind of solution but it won't enjoy the defining properties of a projection (namely, an idempotent endomorphism of a vector space).

@whuber Interesting. Is it fair to say that this picture breaks down when we move to an objective function in taxicab geometry? Thank you, again for the help.

Yes, that's fair.
